# Talend tCreateTable error: NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, etl, talend

Trying to create a table in a local instance of SQL Server Mgmt Studio using Talend with the ultimate goal of setting up a direct Salesforce-SSMS connection for ETL.

I've managed to load the data from SFDC into SSMS, but only by first manually creating the tables, manually mapping the schema in a tMap, and then running my job.

I'd like to now create the tables in SSMS with a tCreateTable component, and then use the AutoMap feature to map fields.

However, I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception error that makes no sense to me.  Debugging line 370 shows that my dbSchema_tCreateTable_1 object is null, but I don't understand why.  I've defined it from repository.   Below are some pics of my setup:

[Sample Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx0eI.png)

[Error Message and Job Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXKUW.png)

[Line 370 and suspect in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWTf2.png)

I know my db connection is good because I've already pushed data to existing tables, but for the life of me (and 2 of my java engineers) I can't figure this out.  I've got 5 days of experience with Talend so apologies if I'm making a dumb mistake.  Any help would be appreciated!

edit: [Component view of tCreateTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNMWh.png)

edit 2: [Component view of tFixedFlowInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UNqY.png)

edit 3: [Component view of tMSSqlOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dhOi.png)

edit 4: [tMSSqlConnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQbnX.png)

Comment: Hi Ethan, could you please remove the default of 0 from your column in your sample schema definition (leave it empty, no whitespace), and try again ?

Comment: @iMezouar still doesn't work, same NPE error.  Are there any other screenshots I could provide that would be useful?

Comment: Could you please post the component's view of tCreateTable ?

Comment: @iMezouar of course, added in edit. Let me know if you need more

Comment: That seems all right to me. Now could you please add an OnSubjobOk trigger  between your tMSSqlConnection and tCreateTable ?

Comment: @iMezouar added the trigger, still fails

Comment: Sorry, that's about all I could think of off the top of my head, I'll look into it as soon as I get to the office in the morning, where I have access to a SQL Server instance.

Comment: @iMezouar no problem, i appreciate the help!  Please let me know if you have some time in the morning, though I'm in California so we have different mornings!

Comment: Could you please try one more thing: tMSSqlConnection - OnSubjobOk - tFixedFlowInput (has a single column MasterRecordId with a random string) - Main - tMSSqlOutput (table test, with create table option selected). An alternative to creating a table using tCreateTable

Comment: @iMezouar didn't work, added a screenshot of tFixedFlowInput to the post in case that helps

Comment: Could you please post the error message ?

Comment: @iMezouar same as before, but now the line is different likely because the job has more components:

"Exception in component tMSSqlOutput_1 (tableCreate_test)
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at local_project.tablecreate_test_0_1.tableCreate_test.tFixedFlowInput_1Process(tableCreate_test.java:539)
 at local_project.tablecreate_test_0_1.tableCreate_test.runJobInTOS(tableCreate_test.java:1224)
 at local_project.tablecreate_test_0_1.tableCreate_test.main(tableCreate_test.java:1073)
["

Comment: This leads me to believe the error might come from a misconfiguration of tMSSqlConnection. Could you please post its component view (replacing sensitive info with dummy values), I'm especially interested in the schema

Comment: @iMezouar added screenshot.  The schema is the same as the screenshot labeled Sample Schema, except I removed the default value of 0 as you suggested earlier.

Comment: tMSSqlConnection not tMSSqlOutput :) and by schema I meant sql server databse schema, not Talend schema.

Comment: @iMezouar my mistake!  added a screenshot.  I've tried it with schema blank, schema "test", and our internal schema value.  All gives the same error message

Comment: Have you tried with dbo schema ?

Comment: @iMezouar yes that is what we use, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

On first job (provided on Error Message and Job Design) NPE occur because of connection still not created (is null) when tCreateTable tried to call null.executeStatement()
You can modify your first job put tMsSQLConnection -> OnSubjobOK -> tCreateTable
OR remove connection element at all and set connection parameters to tCreateTable.

If it doesn't help, answer please on following questions:

Share please exception stacktrace and error message occurs when you use second job (connection -> tFixedFlowInput - tMSSQLOutput)
What version of studio (Open Studio or enterprise and version) have you used?
If it is not the latest (6.5.1) could you upgrade it?
If it is, could you export your job and share it? (i.e. on talend bug tracker)

P.S. You can try to debug job by yourself, select Run Job -> Debug Run -> Java Debug [image]

Using eclipse debug view you can find out why the NPE occur.